# Editing protected Custom Metadata Type in subscriber org through LMA org

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata

I do have verified that the Protected custom settings are editable when logged in through LMA org. However, I just want to confirm this behavior is the same in the case of the protected Custom Metadata Type records.

Also, the metadata record is upgradable via Package/Patch release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question - and based on a quick test now, I believe the answer is no - you cannot see/edit protected Custom Metadata in an subscriber org when you login via LMA Org. The only CMD objects I can see are ones marked as public by the package

But to answer the second question, yes, you can add/update CMD records via package upgrade process if they are marked as protected in the package

There are limitations to be aware of though:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_req_managed_pkgs.htm&type=5

And make sure to read the ISV Guide for full details about what is upgradeable and deleteable:
https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/220/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_packaging_guide.pdf

Comment: Thanks for testing this out BritishBoyinDC! So ideally one can push the update for CMD records. Actually I have a scenario where I need to store the endpoints and API key to be referred by my package's code. In this case, going with protected CMD makes more sense than Custom settings as CS will need the script on installation to create/update record. Please suggest if this approach seems right?

Comment: For the endpoints, I would actually recommend using Named Credentials - that way, you get the whitelisting you need to avoid unauthorized endpoints.
API key might be ok, but you want to check with Security Review team to ensure that complies with their rules around secure storage

Comment: Thanks for this alternative, I will check all these alternatives with the Security review team. Will keep you posted on the solution.